# Add SNS filter Policy via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to add SNS filter for DynamoDB updates by means of CloudFormation, but seems like latter one don't support nulls while I need to add a filter by nullable field..

I aim to get updates only for rows that have parentId NOT NULL, I did the following:

`SNSSubscription: Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription Properties: Protocol: sqs TopicArn: Fn::ImportValue: !Sub MyTopic Endpoint: !GetAtt MySQS.Arn RawMessageDelivery: true FilterPolicyScope: MessageBody FilterPolicy: { "Records": { "dynamodb": { "NewImage": { "parentId": { "S" : {"anything-but": [null]} } } } } }`

While syntax from above is absolutely valid CloudFormation keep saying

> 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Is there any way to overcome this limitation somehow?
Any advise is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You syntax doesn't make sense, at least for DynamoDB. In DynamoDB there is no such thing as a `null` string, as `null` is a separate data type in DynamoDB, its impossible to `null` any other data type. So if your template were to work, it would always evaluate to `True`.

You would probably make better use of `exists` matching:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-exists-matching